# help debugging thread (AsyncTask) RuntimeException cause in Android/Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, runtime

I have several AsyncTask worker threads, and during runtime one of them shows up in Eclipse as "exception RuntimeException."  I am having trouble finding out the cause of the exception, or even what thread/code was running.

All I see is Thread 11, AsyncTask #2.  Beneath, it says:

```
Thread.run() line: 1096
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 561
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1086
```

none of which give me hints what code caused the exception.  I inspected the variables, but I also do not see any hints of this.  I do not see anything about an exception in my LogCat either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I do not see anything about an exception in my LogCat either.

Chances are the program pauses itself and you are not resuming it with the Eclipse debugger. Only after that will the Exception be show in the console.

Comment: you are right! after resuming, I get a bunch of error information in the log.  This is much more helpful now.  thank you!